# TypeError: Cannot read property ':Lottery.sol' of undefined. Please help in solving this!

Tags: contract-deployment

I am a newbie and have just started building contracts. I am getting this error for
this contract. Kindly help in solving this[image]

Code-

For **compile.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');



const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'utf-8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Lottery'];
```

For **Lottery.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25; 


contract Lottery{
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;
    
    function lottery() public{
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function enter() public payable{
        require(msg.value > 0.01 ether);
        
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function random() private view returns (uint){
        return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now, players));
    }
    
    function pickWinner() public restricted{
        
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(this.balance);
        players = new address[](0);
    }
    
    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
    
    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[] memory){
        return players;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your code looks like?????

Comment: BTW, your question says "during deployment", but the screenshot shows "npm run test", which is a different thing, so please get your stuff straight together!

Comment: Do migrations run?

Comment: I am sorry... I am a newbie, And I have just added my code. Thanks for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, try this:

**Instead of:**

```
module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[‘:Lottery’];
```

**Do this:**

```
compiledContracts = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;
extractedLottery = compiledCon[:Lottery];
module.exports = extractedLottery;
```